# Handling undefined fields when creating a custom javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, undefined, validation, defensive-programming

I've always created javascript objects in the following way:

```
//object code
function someObject() {
    this.field1;
    this.fiend2;
}

function makeSomeObject(data) {
    var result = new someObject();  
    result.field1 = data.field1DataName;
    result.fiend2 = data.field2DataName;
    return result;
}

//object instantiation
var someObject = makeSomeObject(data);
processObject(someObject);
```

I now want to do this more defensively. In other words I want to test data.field1DataName before setting it. I'm attempting to do this in the following way.

```
//object code
function someObject() {
    this.field1;
    this.fiend2;
}

function makeSomeObject(data){
    var result = new someObject(); 
    result.field1 = typeof data != "undefined"  ? "field1DataNameUndefined": data.field1DataName;
    result.field2 = typeof data != "undefined"  ? "field2DataNameUndefined": data.field2DataName;
    return result;
}

//object instantiation
var someObject = makeSomeObject(data);
processObject(someObject);
```

Now if a data field is missing that will be caught before the object field is set. The problem is that the `someObject` still gets created and `processObject` will accept it with out knowing there a problem. My question is what is the best practice for indicating that there's a problem with `someObject` so I can avoid problems in `processObject`. If anyone has any suggestions for a better practices for defensive programming in javascript in the course of considering this issue that feedback is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally do it, with some sort of `extend` method, and a `.defaults = {}` object, jQuery's works in this case.

```
function SomeObject(data) {
    $.extend(this, SomeObject.defaults, data);
}

SomeObject.defaults = {
    field1: '',
    field2: ''
};

var newObject = new SomeObject({ field1: 'field1' });

console.log(newObject);
// > { field1: 'field1', field2: '' }
```

You could say that we have defined a default mixin for `SomeObject`, since we are `$.extend`ing `this`. This way we can let `$.extend` handle the `null`/`undefined` checks.

As far as handling errors in the object you can initialize your defaults to `null` and `throw new Error()` when something is not passed in.

```
function SomeObject(data) {
    $.extend(this, SomeObject.defaults, data);
    if (this.field1 == null) {
        throw new Error('SomeObject: field1 is required');
    }
}

SomeObject.defaults = {
    field1: null,
    field2: null
};

var newObject = new SomeObject({ field2: 'field2' });
// > Error: SomeObject: field1 is required
```

Two great articles about throwing errors

- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/
- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/10/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors-part-2/